# Lottie Animation does not play again on Android after reset()

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

I am using Expo and React Native and I want to display a Lottie animation. On iOS this works like a charm - on Android the animation will play once and then it will not play again. It seems that `reset()` somehow behaves strange.

What am I doing wrong here? You can also have a look at a corresponding [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@raider/lottie-).

```
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

import likeAnimation from './assets/animation.json';

export default function App() {
  const animation = useRef(null);

  const onPress = () => {
    animation.current.play();
  };

  const onAnimationFinish = () => {
    animation.current.reset();
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 200, backgroundColor: '#dddddd', flex: 1 }}>
      <LottieView
        loop={false}
        speed={1.5}
        autoSize
        ref={animation}
        source={likeAnimation}
        onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
      />
      <Button onPress={onPress} title="Click me!" />

    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/676